# Fatal error: Uncaught ActiveCollab

Tags: php, ssl, sdk, activecollab

I've prepared some scripts on my local, and everything works properly... but when I just upload all files on server, and run script I have following error:

***Fatal error: Uncaught ActiveCollab\SDK\Exceptions\CallFailed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to project.*****.com:443 in ......./activecollab/src/Connector.php:208........***

On server is php 7.1 , and cURL is also installed...

do you have any suggestions what could be a problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hard to say, without providing code or other information. You could try to send an cURL request from the terminal of your server. Seems like your server can not handle/verify ssl certificate from requested server (project.w-em.com). Maybe you have to install some additional certificates on your system. Just an idea from "unknown SSL protocoll error...".

Comment: ActiveCollab SDK uses cURL to execute HTTP requests. “Unknown SSL protocol error in connection” is error thrown by cURL, and there are plenty of articles online that offer advice how to troubleshoot it (for example: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html). Just search for the error message up to the project.w-em.com, and you’ll find a lot of resources.

Comment: @Ilija thank you for the answer, however, I still have no solution. I do not think the problem is up to the host because when I test from my local everything works properly? Any suggestion would be great...

Comment: I would advise you to give this a second thought: "I do not think the problem is up to the host because when I test from my local everything works properly?" 

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCollab SDK uses cURL to execute HTTP requests. “Unknown SSL protocol error in connection” is error thrown by cURL, and there are plenty of articles online that offer advice how to troubleshoot it (for example: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html). Just search for the error message up to the project.w-em.com ("Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to"), and you’ll find a lot of resources that cover this class of cURL errors.

Comment: One more question, if I remove https from my domain everything should be ok everywhere? So is it possible to buy just another licence (domain) and enable this domain just for my IP list? and how much is additional licence (domain)?